# Passing an hash to a Capybara Selector

Tags: capybara

I have a custom Capybara selector

```
module Selectors
  Capybara.add_selector(:dataAttribute) do
    xpath { |attribute| ".//*[@data-target='#{attribute}']" }
  end
end


find(:dataAttribute, 'myButton')
```

And it works just fine.

Now I need to generalize it and be able to pass also the data attribute so I can find for instance `<div data-behavior"hideYourself">...</div>`.

Ideally, I'd like to have the API below

```
find(:dataAttribute, attribute: 'behavior', value: 'hideYourself')
#OR
find(:dataAttribute, { attribute: 'behavior', value: 'hideYourself' })
```

So, I have updated my selector as follows

```
module Selectors
  Capybara.add_selector(:dataAttribute) do
    xpath { |params| ".//*[@data-#{params[:attribute]}='#{params[:value]}']" }
  end
end
```

But I get `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.
I have done a bit of debugging and I noticed in the current selector (1 string parameter) the value in the block is correctly set (`myButton` for instance). However, when I pass the hash the value is `nil`.

Any idea how to pass multiple params to a selector?

`find(:dataAttribute, 'behavior', 'hideYourself')` may be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybaras find takes the selector type, an optional locator, and then options.  The problem you're running into is if you pass a Hash as a second parameter and then no third parameter that is interpreted as no locator passed and an options hash. Because of this you could use your selector as written by passing an empty options hash so the attribute/value hash is interpreted as the locator

```
find(:dataAttribute, attribute: 'behavior', value: 'hideYourself', {})
```

This could all then be wrapped up in a `find_data_attribute` helper method so you wouldn't have to manually pass the empty options hash.

```
def find_data_attribute(locator, **options)
  find(:dataAttribute, locator, options)
end
```

Another option would be write your selector differently and use options instead - something like

```
Capybara.add_selector(:dataAttribute) do
  xpath(:attribute, :value) do |_locator, attribute:, value:, **| 
    ".//*[@data-#{attribute}='#{value}']"
  end
end
```

which tells the selector to expect :attribute and :value options to be passed in which would allow `find(:dataAttribute, attribute: 'behavior', value: 'hideYourself')` to work.

A final option is to use a wildcard option matcher along the lines of

```
Capybara.add_selector(:dataAttribute) do
  xpath do |_locator, **|
    #you could use the locator to limit by element type if wanted - see Capybaras built-in :element selector - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L467
    XPath.descendant
  end

  expression_filter(:attributes, matcher: /.+/) do |xpath, name, val|
    xpath[XPath.attr("data-#{name}")==val]
  end
end
```

Which should then allow you to do

```
find(:dataAttribute, behavior: 'hideYourself')
```

to find by one data attribute or

```
find(:dataAttribute, behavior: 'hideYourself', other_data_attr_name: 'some value')
```

to find by multiples

Comment: Thanks for the broad response. I ended up using the second option you highlighted.